# linq to entities: compare string variable with NVarchar field

Tags: string, linq, equality, varchar, entities

This code results in timeout exception

```
String City_Code = null;
var result = (from r in myContext.TableA
                  where ( City_Code == r.City_Code )
                  select r ).ToList();
```

while this code will return quickly

```
String City_Code = null;
var result = (from r in myContext.TableA
                  where ( r.City_Code == City_Code ) 
                  select r ).ToList();
```

The difference is in the order of operands of the equality. The field City_Code of table TableA is of type nvarchar(20).

What is a possible reason for that???

update: The generated tsql for the 2 queries are identical except for that part: the first one has the condition " @p__linq__2 = [Extent1].[City_Code])" while the second has " [Extent1].[City_Code] = @p__linq__2)"

The value of @p_linq_2 when I notice the time difference is NULL. If I run the queries in ssms with NULL in place of @p_linq_2 they respond both very quickly

Comment: Your code isn't complete as it is missing `select` and won't compile. BTW, what LINQ provider?

Comment: your LINQ queries are missing `select`s, which should prevent that code from compiling.  With the selects added, and running against a SQL server db using Linq2Sql, both run fine, taking the same amount of time. I guess in reducing your code to example size, you removed something important.

Comment: Is `City_Code` indexed?

Comment: The original code includes "select r".  What I posted here is just an example. I added the "select r" in my question so you do not get confused. Also City_Code is indexed.  Any other idea?  I remark that both queries are running but the first one is much slower and it seems weird since in tsql they would be the same